# Extraction of characters in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like that

```
Sample Marker1 Marker2 Marker 3             
Sample1 230/250 301/302 140/150          
Sample2 233/255 304/306 143/158       
Sample3 221/250 304/310 140/152
```

and I would like to get to separate the figures on both sides of the / sign to get this. So each column will be divided in 2 :

```
Sample  Marker1a Marker1b Marker2a Marker2b Marker3a Marker3b             
Sample1 230      250      301      302      140      150          
Sample2 233      255      304      306      143      158       
Sample3 221      250      304      310      140      152
```

I am trying to use list to do that without success. Maybe somebody here will have a better idea? 
Anne-Sophie

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Add something that you've tried already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
# create dataframe
d <- read.table(text='Sample Marker1 Marker2 Marker3             
                Sample1 230/250 301/302 140/150          
                Sample2 233/255 304/306 143/158       
                Sample3 221/250 304/310 140/152 ', 
                header=T, stringsAsFactor=F)

# loop over the Marker columns
for (col in paste0('Marker', 1:3)){

  # create a list of splitted values
  splitted.values <- strsplit(d[[col]], '/')
  # add the first item of each list element to a
  d[[paste0(col, 'a')]] <- sapply(splitted.values, '[', 1)
  # add the second item of each list element to b
  d[[paste0(col, 'b')]] <- sapply(splitted.values, '[', 2)
}

print(d)

   Sample Marker1 Marker2 Marker3 Marker1a Marker1b Marker2a Marker2b Marker3a Marker3b
1 Sample1 230/250 301/302 140/150      230      250      301      302      140      150
2 Sample2 233/255 304/306 143/158      233      255      304      306      143      158
3 Sample3 221/250 304/310 140/152      221      250      304      310      140      152
```

Comment: Thank you bobbel and @jasbner

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `tidyr` library and `separate`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% separate(Marker1,c("Marker1a","Marker1b")) %>% separate(Marker2,c("Marker2a","Marker2b")) %>% separate(Marker3,c("Marker3a","Marker3b"))
#   Sample Marker1a Marker1b Marker2a Marker2b Marker3a Marker3b
#1 Sample1      230      250      301      302      140      150
#2 Sample2      233      255      304      306      143      158
#3 Sample3      221      250      304      310      140      152
```